# ExtJS 4: ask user in standart button before click

Tags: extjs

I need to ask user (with standart Ext.MessageBox.confirm dialog) before actually do the click event, because in the href config is set server's php scenario.

When I clicked the button ExtJS first called the php scenario (in other browser's window - it's by default) and only after that shows MessageBox dialog.
But I am need first to ask user and call php scenario only if he said 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

```
function   yoursMethod([config])
{
 // call you sripts there
 // check what a button you pressed and then call scenario
 // you can see [config] in documentation http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox-method-show
 }

Ext.MessageBox.confirm({
   title: ' Sample ',
   msg: 'Message',
   fn: yoursMethod
});
```